# How to create a params dict from **kwargs in an if chain in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an API wrapper for a weather API. Here are two snippets of my code, which don't quite work:

```py
def payload_helper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        paylouad = args
    else:
        payload = {
            "units": "metric",
        }
    payload.update(kwargs)
    return payload
```

```py
def weather(self, lat="", lon="", zip_code=""):
    payload = self.payload_helper()
    if lat:
        payload = self.payload_helper(payload, lat=lat)
    elif lon:
        payload = self.payload_helper(payload, lon=lon)
    elif zip_code:
        payload = self.payload_helper(payload, zip_code=zip_code)
```

The goal of payload helper is to create a dict that adds a set to:

1. if no payload is passed: a new payload dict
2. if a payload is passed: update the payload and return the new (merged) one

I know I could solve this if I would just make `weather(self, *args, **kwargs)` but I don't want that. I always find it nice if the user that uses the API wrapper also has intelli sense (see what variables the method expects), which is not possible with `**kwargs`. I don't have to do this with the `if elif else` chain. This was just my approach. There is probably a mew *python* way of doing this.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You're looking to add all the named arguments from the method to a dictionary, correct?

Comment: How I can create the payload dict in the if chain. Because right now, my payload dict is always only len = 1. Which I don't understand. Even if I pass both lat and lon.

Comment: @Grismar Yes, that explains it even better. But these arguments can be empty.

Comment: You probably don't want to chain those `if..elif..elif`, but just have a bunch of separate `if`s?

Comment: I voted to reopen - I think the question is clear (and an obvious solution could be presented with `locals()`). It's not at all due to a typo or anything of the sort and the question should not have been closed for such a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your main goal seems to be that you want to create a dictionary that contains all the keyword arguments that were included in the call to your original function.

A very straightforward way to achieve what you want:

```
def func(a="", b="", c=""):
    payload = locals()
    # do something else
    print(payload)


func(a=1, b='2', c=3.)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3.0}
```

But note that your idea to define the keyword parameters as empty strings means they are implicitly strings. This will lead to a decent IDE giving you all warnings about the types of the arguments being passed.

A better way would be to specify their type, but set them to be `None` initially. `Optional` helps to allow the `None` value in spite of their type:

```
from typing import Optional


def func(a: Optional[int] = None, b: Optional[str] = None, c: Optional[float] = None):
    payload = {name: value for name, value in locals().items() if value is not None}
    # do something else
    print(payload)


func(b='2', c=3.)  # no warnings
```

Result:

```
{'b': '2', 'c': 3.0}
```

Note that the solution above does have the (perhaps unwanted) side effect of including any positional arguments as well. For example:

```
def func(a: int, b: Optional[int] = None):
    payload = locals()
    # do something else
    print(payload)


func(1, 2)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

It's relevant, because your functions appear to be methods, so they will at least have the positional parameter `self`, which would need to be removed:

```
from typing import Optional


class MyClass:
    def func(self, x: Optional[int] = None):
        payload = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if v is not None and k != 'self'}
        # do something else
        print(payload)


mc = MyClass()
mc.func()
mc.func(1)
```

Result:

```
{}
{'x': 1}
```

Also note that, if you need your keyword arguments to actually be able to have the value `None` assigned, the above still need some extra work, and you might look into `__defaults__`.

On a more general note: have you looked at `dataclasses` at all? Because it seems that what you're ultimately after might be better achieved using those.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the helper should do is filter out `None`-valued arguments to `weather`. The "base" payload should be created in `weather` itself, then updated using the return value of the helper.

```
def weather(self, lat=None, lon=None, zip_code=None):
    def helper(**kwargs):
        return {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}

    payload = {'units': 'metric'}
    payload.update(helper(lat=lat, lon=lon, zip_code=zip_code))
    
    ...
```